# jQuery - Setting field values in the action page while loading it through the load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two html pages, directory.html and customer.html

I'm trying to set values to the text fields presented in my action page (customer.html) from my directory.html page.

I'm using the jQuery's load function to load my directory page, Can someone please guide me how I can set the text field's value (automatically) as soon as I load the action page through the load function?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Use the load-finished callback in the load function:

```
   //Store customer.html form field values here.
   var field1 = $('#field1').val();
   $("#directory").load("directory.html", {var:'value'}, function(){
       //load the info from the first page here
       $('#field1').val(field1);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately I'm not able to get it working